# Complex relationship between tables in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, automapping

I'm writing a Fluent NHibernate mapping for a legacy Oracle database. The challenge is that the tables have composite primary keys. If I were at total freedom, I would redesign the relationships and auto-generate primary keys, but other applications must write to the same database and read from it, so I cannot do it.

These are the two tables I'll focus on:

[image]

### Example data

```
Trips table:
1, 10:00, 11:00 ...
1, 12:00, 15:00 ...
1, 16:00, 19:00 ...
2, 12:00, 13:00 ...
3, 9:00, 18:00 ...

Faults table:
1, 13:00 ...
1, 23:00 ...
2, 12:30 ...
```

In this case, vehicle 1 made three trips and has two faults. The first fault happened during the second trip, and the second fault happened while the vehicle was resting. Vehicle 2 had one trip, during which a fault happened.

### Constraints

Trips of the same vehicle never overlap. So the tables have an **optional one-to-many relationship,** because every fault either happens during a trip or it doesn't. If I wanted to join them in SQL, I would write:

```
select ... 
from Faults left outer join Trips
  on Faults.VehicleId = Trips.VehicleId
  and Faults.FaultTime between Trips.TripStartTime and Trips.TripEndTime
```

and then I'd get a dataset where **every fault appears exactly once** (one-to-many as I said).

Note that there is no Vehicles table, and I don't need one. But I did create a view that contains all VehicleIds from both tables, so I can use it as a junction table.

### What am I actually looking for?

The tables are huge because they cover years of data, and every time I only need to fetch a range of a few hours.

So I need a mapping and a criteria that will run something like the following SQL underneath:

```
select ... 
from Faults left outer join Trips
  on Faults.VehicleId = Trips.VehicleId
  and Faults.FaultTime between Trips.TripStartTime and Trips.TripEndTime
where Faults.FaultTime between :p0 and :p1
```

Do you have any ideas how to achieve it?

**Note 1:** Currently the application shouldn't write to the database, so persistence is not a must, although if the mapping supports persistence, it may help at some point in the future.

**Note 2:** I know it's a tough one, so if you give me a great answer, you will be properly rewarded :)

Thank you for reading this long question, and now I only hope for the best :)

Comment: What version of NH are you using? NH3 with Linq2NH support?

Answer (score 3):

### Current Recommendation

Given the additional information in the comments, I would now propose trying the following class mappings instead of using any of the custom SQL solutions mentioned further down this answer:

```
<class name="Fault" table="Faults">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="VehicleId" />
    <key-property name="FaultTime" />
    <key-property name="FaultType" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id> 
  <many-to-one name="Trip" class="Trip">
    <!-- Composite Key of Trip is calculated on the fly -->
    <formula>VehicleId</formula>
    <formula>
      ( SELECT  TripStartTime 
        FROM    Trips t 
        WHERE   VehicleId = t.VehicleId 
        AND     FaultTime BETWEEN t.TripStartTime AND t.TripEndTime
      )
    </formula>
  </many-to-one>
  ...
</class> 

<class name="Trip" table="Trips">
  <composite-id>
    <key-property name="VehicleId" />
    <key-property name="TripStartTime" />
  </composite-id> 
  ...
</class>
```

Using this mapping you can load and query the Fault entities however you like.

### Obsolete Suggestions

I originally considered a (named) custom SQL query here. You could enter the following query in your mapping file to load Fault objects with for a given vehicle:

```
<sql-query name="LoadFaultsAndTrips" xml:space="preserve">
  <return class="Fault" alias="f"/>
  <return-join alias="t" property="f.Trip"/>
  SELECT  {f.*}
      ,   {t.*}
  FROM    Faults f
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Trips t 
      ON f.VehicleId = t.VehicleId
      AND f.FaultTime BETWEEN t.TripStartTime AND t.TripEndTime
  WHERE f.VehicleId = ?
</sql-query>
```

If you need to load the Faults collection on a Vehicle object without explicit queries you could try the following mapping construct in XML:

```
<class name="Vehicle">
   <id name="VehicleId" type="...">
     <generator class="..." />
   </id>
   ...
   <bag name="Faults" table="Faults" inverse="true">
     <key column="VehicleId" />
     <loader query-ref="VehicleFaultsLoader" />
   </bag>
   ...
</class>

<sql-query name="VehicleFaultsLoader" xml:space="preserve">
  <load-collection role="Vehicle.Faults" alias="f" />
  <return-join alias="t" property="f.Trip"/>
  SELECT  {f.*}
      ,   {t.*}
  FROM    Faults f
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Trips t 
      ON f.VehicleId = t.VehicleId
      AND f.FaultTime BETWEEN t.TripStartTime AND t.TripEndTime
  WHERE f.VehicleId = ?
</sql-query>
```

The key here is to define a custom collection loader for the Faults collection on the Vehicle class and to define a custom SQL query that receives the primary key of Vehicle as parameter. I haven't used fluent NHibernate yet myself, so I'm afraid I cannot help you with that part of the question.

Cheers,
Gerke.

Comment: Thank you, I'll search for ways to translate it into Fluent.

Comment: Your answer has been very enlightening. And yet it doesn't address all the problems, so I have two follow-up questions:

1. I never want to select ALL trips and faults of a vehicle. I only want to select some based on time. What I think I need is a many-to-one reference between Fault and Trip based on this complicated query. How do I select faults and trips by time?

2. In the first query, will NH create the Fault and Trip objects out of the fields that it gets as results from the query? The results seem to be a dataset with a lot of columns, so is NH smart enough to divide them into objects?

Comment: And another question: Doesn't the mapping you suggested imply that I have a Vehicles table? (because I don't... I can create a Vehicles view, but it still doesn't solve the loading-by-time problem).

Comment: Sounds like the first named query is the way to go in your scenario. You can add additional parameters to limit the returned rows. That query would return Fault instances with the Trip property optionally set (indeed using a ManyToOneMapping for the Trip property on the Fault class).

Comment: Just to clarify, instead of the WHERE VehicleId = ? in the LoadFaultsAndTrips query, you could enter an arbitrary other WHERE statement with all the parameters you need.

Comment: Hi @Gerke. What I'm looking for is building a relationship between entities that will enable me to write `fault.Trip` or at least `fault.Trips`. Is this what the first named query does? Should I then not mention the relationship between Fault and Trip in the mapping?

Answer (score 2):

You example sql there is syntactically the same as

```
select ... 
from Faults left join Trips
  on Faults.VehicleId = Trips.VehicleId
where Faults.VehicleId is null or (Faults.FaultTime between Trips.TripStartTime and Trips.TripEndTime)
```

with this in mind, you can create a regular map such as (fluent)

```
HasMany< Trip >( fault => fault.Trips )
    .KeyColumn( "VehicleId" )
    .Table( "Trips" )
    .LazyLoad( )
    .Cascade.Delete( )
    .AsSet()
```

then using what every form of querying you are comfortable with, be it hql, icriteria, icriteriaover or linq do your standard query with a where clause as mentioned above.

in linq that would be:

```
IList<Trip> results = 
( 
    fault in Session.Query< Entities.Faults > 
    join trip in Session.Query< Entities.Trips > on fault.VehicleId equals trip.VehicleId into trip
    where
    fault.FaultTime > startTime && fault.FaultTime < endTime &&
    // Here is the rest of the join criteria expressed as a where criteria
    (
        trip == null
            || 
        (
            fault.FaultTime > trip.TripStartTime && fault.FaultTime < trip.TripEndTime
        ) 
    )
    select fault
).ToList();
```

If need be I can give you an example in ICriteria or IQueryOver.

Of course this only work because of the example statement you provided can be re-written as a where clause while having the result. If you real world desired sql is more complex you'd need to think if the desired sql can be re-written while archiving the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to NH and only know NH rudiments, so when I've hit a situation like this I've written a stored proc and then [called it](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx) through NH.  Eventually I'll find an all-NH solution, and then I'll refactor the code and remove the necessity for the stored proc.

Another approach that might work is to just write the [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) you need.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to HQL. Since your reply I've been reading some info about HQL, but I still haven't figured out how to apply it in my case. Can you please give me a more specific idea of what to do? Meanwhile I'm also trying @Gerke's approach. Anyway stored procedures is not something I want to find my way into, unless I must.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan - Yes, my methods are last resorts, and I was thinking along the lines of cdmdotnet's answer, but using HQL rather than linq.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a suggestion, if you are using NHibernate 3, try Linq to NH. Using Linq you can specify manualy/arbitrary relationships for a once off execution, or use pipes if you think it's going to be re-used (or being linq if you want to do a left/right join you need to specify it, if it's an isser join you don't need to specify a join at all, its all inferred from the mappings) and is business logic and not persitence logic.

As a quick example it would be somethng like:

```
var result = ( 
fault in Session.Query< Entities.Faults > 
join trip in Session.Query< Entities.Trips > on fault.VehicleId equals trip.VehicleId into trip
where 
fault.FaultTime > startTime && fault.FaultTime < endTime &&
fault.FaultTime > trip.TripStartTime && fault.FaultTime < trip.TripEndTime
select fault
).ToList();
```

I've written this by hand so it might not be perfect, but close enough. This should do exactly what you need, and allow you to change it as you see fit without changing you mappings.

Comment: Actually I tried using LINQ to NH, but it doesn't give any added value except for the clearer syntax. The `<` and `>` don't get translated into `<` and `>` in SQL. What LINQ to HN does is running a SELECT statement that loads the entire table and then returning only part of the results. Anyway, even if the restrictions did work, this is just a querying technique, and it still won't enable me to write things like `fault.Trip` in my code which is what I need.

Comment: To resolve your issue of the "fault.Trip", if you changed "select fault" to something more suitable. then you can get either an annoymous type with what ever structure you want, or project it into a concrete class, such as your Trip class. As for you comment about no added value, as i said, run time arbitrary relationships has its uses. But I'm guessing it might not be suitable to this application.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know what query you want the DB to execute, why not just execute the query directly using your own custom DAO class? Why bother with the NHibernate abstraction, if it's just getting in the way?

Comment: Because NHibernate has a lot of other advantages. It's true that this particular query is a hard nut, but the rest of the application will benefit a lot from NHibernate, and I'm sure I'll get over this problem as well.

Comment: Besides, the fact that I know what query I want to execute is irrelevant. Everybody who knows SQL can write any query for any database no worse than an OR-M can, but it doesn't mean OR-Ms are useless.